# php use one direction back

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I'm trying to get working `use`.

My file is in /application/controllers/indexController.php

```
use application\models\Database;

class IndexController extends Controller {

    public function indexAction() {
        $db = new Database();
        $this->view->render('index','template');
    }
}
```

My Database class is in /application/models/Database.php so i wrote use application\models\Database

But it tells

> Fatal error: Class 'application\models\Database' not found in
>   Z:\home\localhost\www\application\controllers\IndexController.php on
>   line 7

How i can get it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`use` is **not** magical.

You need an autoloader to tell it where to find a certain namespace.

So right now your code is looking for a class called `application\models\Database` in the same directory as your currently executing file.

I *think* what you meant to do is:

```
include 'application\models\Database.php';
```

Comment: Okay ill look whats auto loader

Comment: In your example you need to do an `include` @user3005741